# p:dialog with resizable="true" doesn't resize when its p:inputTextarea resizes

Tags: primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` with `resizable="true"` and it contains a `p:inputTextarea`, which is also resizable:

```
<p:dialog header="Comment" widgetVar="commentDialog" modal="true" resizable="true" height="100">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel for="comment" value="Comment:"/>

        <p:inputTextarea id="comment" title="Comment" 
                rows="6" cols="33"
                value="#{managedBean.comment}"
                required="true" styleClass="plainInput"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

However, as I enter more text into the text area than its initial capacity, the text area does resize but the dialog does not.

How do I make the dialog resize together with the text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `height="100"` attribute or set it to `height="auto"` instead.

*Tested in Primefaces 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

set the `minHeight` and `minWidth` attributes.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. because in the resize event there is condition that check if the new height / width bigger than minHeight/width. if there are equal to null it doesnt change to the new size. I try it and it help!